# Sklearn random forest model is too big

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Question from the beginner in `sklearn`, please advise.
I have `RandomForestClassifier` model trained with the following parameters:

```
n_estimators = 32,
criterion = 'gini',
max_depth = 380,
```

This parameters are not randomly chosen, for some reason they showed the best performance...though seem strange to myself.

The model size is about **5.5GB** when saved with `joblib.dump` and `compress=3`

The data used is:

```
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer()
X_train=tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
```

**and**

```
le=LabelEncoder()
le.fit(y_train)
y_train=le.fit_transform(y_train)
```

with a sample size of 4.7Mio records splitted 0.3 (70% train, 30% test)

Now, I have a question, maybe someone can help with:

Does it make sense to you the Parameters used for the model and the size of the model in respect to the size of the sample? Probably the choice of the parameters is not optimal for the model that increases the size (I do understand that the main parameter increasing the size here is `max_depth`, but the result was the best...)

Maybe there is any suggestions on the Parameters or data preparation in general, as in my experience with this sample, I noticed the following:
1. Increasing `n_estimators` makes almost no difference on the outcome;
2. Increasing `max_depth` on the other hand brings significant improvements. As example: 
- `max_depth = 10` - `accuracy_score` of 0.3
- `max_depth = 380` - `accuracy_score` of 0.95

Any suggestions, advise is very welcome!:)

**UPD. Accuracy results**

Train Score: **0.988** `classifier.score`

OOB Score: **0.953** `classifier.oob_score_`

Test Score: **0.935** `sklearn.metrics -> accuracy_score`

Comment: Is accuracy score calculated on test set?

Comment: You maybe overfitting - can you please post your validation score and training score?

Comment: @FChm updated, thank you

Comment: @SeljukGülcan updated

Comment: How much accuracy tradeoff are you experiencing when you do `max_depth=10` or around it?

Comment: @VivekKumar `max_depth=10` brings me down to 0.3-0.35 in Score... (sorry, it is rough number, but it brings me times down.

Comment: @AndreiPopov This sounds very much like an overfitting situation, although you seem to be doing a train/test split. Please provide a full code example that shows clearly how you preprocess the data and compute classifier score, so we can tell if any training data leaks into the test set. Also, add some details where the data is coming from - are you sure the samples are independent?

Comment: Using a RandomForest for a sparse data like text as onehot encoded is quite ... I think this is too expensive as you can see in your 5.5GB of model. Can you provide the shape of `X_train`? This has no relation with your question but try to use a SVC instead.

Comment: How many features and classes do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `min_samples_leaf` instead of max_depth to limit tree depths. This allows different depths for different paths of the tree, and for different estimators. Hopefully making it possible to find a model which has good performance with a lower *average* depth. 
I like to set min_samples_leaf as a float, meaning a fraction of the number of samples. Try gridsearch between (0.0001, 0.1)