# How deploy a big Machine Learning model in an Azure Function?

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, model, azure-functions

I have done a model based on 30'000 texts from a database to classify the source. The code is below :

```
df[['PagePdf', 'ID_Source']] = df [['PagePdf', 'ID_Emetteur']].astype(int)
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W', ' ', x))                # Remove all the special characters
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', x))    # remove all single characters
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', x))     # Remove single characters from the start
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: unidecode(x))                         # Remove accents                        
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', x, flags=re.I))   # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
df            = df.loc[df["Content"].str.len() >= 20].reset_index(drop=True)
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: [word.lemma_ for word in nlp_fr(x)])  # Converting to Lowercase
df['Content'] = df['Content'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))


list_data_X = df['Content'].values
list_data_y = df['ID_Source'].values

# THE NUMBER OF UNIQUE LABELS
labels = np.unique(list_data_y)
print("The number of unique labels : ", len(labels))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=2500, min_df=0.03, max_df=0.85, stop_words=stopwords.words('french'))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(list_data_X).toarray()

tfidfconverter = TfidfTransformer()
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(X).toarray()

# Split the model
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, list_data_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

It generates a pickle file of 70gb. I want to use this model in an Azure Function to predict the source. However I do not know what is the efficient way to do it. I thought to store it in a azure blob storage, however the size of the file is too big to load it in a variable in the Azure Function.

What is the cheapest solution by using Azure Cloud Services and combining it with an Azure function. If anyone has an example or a reference.

Thank you

Comment: you wan't to load 70gb in memory?

Comment: Have you tried to make your model smaller? There's advice for RandomForestClassifier here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118118/sklearn-random-forest-model-is-too-big